# WPF Renamed Property Doesn't Propagate to XAML

Tags: wpf

I'm a little new to WPF so bear with me.  I have a property that is bound in my XAML, but if I rename it (right click --> Refactor --> Rename) in the .cs file it doesn't propagate to the XAML.  Am I doing something wrong?

**EDIT**
Here's my code behind:

```
private string _selectedItem = null;
public string SelectedItemName
{
  get { return _selectedItem; }
  private set
  {
    if (_selectedItem != value)
    {
      _selectedItem = value;
      OnPropertyChanged();
    }
  }
}
```

Here's my XAML:

```
<TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="307,287,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" 
             Text="{Binding SelectedItemName}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Name="txtTest2" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your setter needs to be public. WPF binding system can't change the text when you type into TextBox. The refactoring is never meant to change XAML files. Download ReSharper if you want to have such functionality.

Comment: The Textbox isn't meant to set the value at this point, but that probably would have tripped me up later!  I was afraid that the (lack of) renaming xaml was a feature...Very disappointing, it feels like a step backwards.

Comment: It's impossible to make such feature that wouldn't break existing functionality. ReSharper allows you to do this but it explictly says which parts it's gonna modify.