# Refactoring property name in code behind does not propagate to XAML file

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, xaml, resharper

I'm trying to refactor the property `MyText` to a new name `HerText` in the following solution:

## `MainWindow.xaml.cs`

```
using System.Windows;

namespace resharper_refactoring_xaml
{
   /// <summary>
   /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
   /// </summary>
   public partial class MainWindow : Window
   {
      public MainWindow()
      {
         InitializeComponent();
         MyText = "Blabla";
         DataContext = this;
      }

      public string MyText { get; set; }
   }
}
```

## `MainWindow.Xaml`

```
<Window x:Class="resharper_refactoring_xaml.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:resharper_refactoring_xaml"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
   <Grid>
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=MyText}"></TextBlock>
   </Grid>
</Window>
```

I right click on the property and select *Refactor this > Rename*. Then I type in a new name for the property, hit *Next*.

Unfortunately, only the references of `MyText` in the code-behind are renamed. References to `MyText` in the XAML file rename intact.

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16614353/wpf-renamed-property-doesnt-propagate-to-xaml) Resharper should be able to propagate refactorings to XAML files.

Why is the rename not propagating to the XAML file? Is there some sort of Resharper setting I might have overlooked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason behind this seems to be that ReSharper cannot determine that the property name specified in the  XAML markup refers to the property defined in the `MainWindow` class, *if the `DataContext` property is set in code-behind*.
Bindings refer to the `DataContext` of controls as source by default. If it is not detected, the link between the loose markup and the defining type is lost. I cannot tell if this is a bug in ReSharper or a general limitation.

However, there are two simple solutions to this issue that work for me:

1. Set a design time data context to the type that defines the property here `MainWindow`.

   ```
   <Window ...
           d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type={x:Type local:MainWindow}}">
   ```
2. Set the data context via binding in XAML instead of code-behind.

   ```
   <Window ...
           DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
   ```

Comment: Thanks. That appears to do the job for me.